# On IOS have the back button but also we have one more small back button to switch from app to app, on Android how do they work?

Tags: mobile, android, accessibility, ios

please help me explain my concern

Please tell me what is the back link in the red circle that is only available in ios and no in android, how do they work?
I have tried all sorts of ways to compare and find out but to no avail. Please explain it to me or give me some examples. Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Is this a question about how to technically implement the back link, or a question about the back link's behavior?

Comment: I wonder if it has this on ios, does it have the same on android and how does it work?